# Sorting in R doesn't sort data properly

Tags: r, sorting

I am trying to sort a data frame in R by a single column and whatever method I use to sort it, the data is, not sorted, partially sorted, or in a random order and I don't understand why it is not working.

The data frame has a squad name and a finish position, I am trying to sort by finish position

```
df <- df[order(FinishPos),]
```

when running the code above it puts it in the order:
1,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,2,20,3,4,5,6,7,8,9
so it is sorted in parts but not from 1 to 20 like I want

Comment: Values are character not numeric. Convert them to numeric then sort. Provide example data `dput(mydata)`

Comment: It looks like your finish position is a character value.  This might be relevant. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49084625/sort-strings-by-numbers-inside-them.  If you can change your finish position with `as.numeric` you may get the result you are looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your data is likely `character` (or `factor` ordered on the string variants of them).

Choices:

1. Either convert them to integers (or `numeric`) and sorting will work:

   ```r
   FinishPos <- as.numeric(FinishPos) # or as.integer
   df[order(FinishPos),]
   ```
2. Calc the order based on the numeric conversation (temporary):

   ```r
   df[order(as.numeric(FinishPos)),]
   ```